# Sorting values in Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba

A Pivot table is created using values form a Data Connection.

I saved a macro to sort the values but am now getting a "Subscript out of Range" warning when I try to run it after updating to another connection. I guess the macro script is using a static range that I need to replace so that it can run to whatever Pivot Table results I may have.

But which line of the macro code do I need to replace?

```
Sub SortLargestWarningsCount()

'Find the last used column in a Row
    Dim LastCol As Integer
    With ActiveSheet
        LastCol = .Cells(6, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

Worksheets("WARNINGS").Cells(6, LastCol).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

'Sort from Largest
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("WarningsPivotTable").PivotFields( _
    "[Warnings].[Column5].[Column5]").AutoSort xlDescending, _
    "[Measures].[Count of Column5]", ActiveSheet.PivotTables("WarningsPivotTable"). _
    PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(12), 1
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below to `Sort` the `PivotTable` according to "Warning" `PivotField` :

```
Dim PvtSht As Worksheet
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable

' set the worksheet object where the Pivot-Table is locates
Set PvtSht = Worksheets("WARNINGS")

' set the Pivot-Table object
Set PvtTbl = PvtSht.PivotTables("WarningsPivotTable")

With PvtTbl
    'Sort from Largest for PivotFiels "Warning"
    .PivotFields("Warning").AutoSort xlDescending, "Warning"
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply.

Getting an "Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable class" error.

Is it because I would need to replace the "Warning" below by the column/field I want to sort it? If so, the column/field I want to sort is the Grand Totals.

PivotFields("Warning").AutoSort xlDescending, "Warning"